# Mitigating Transitory Effects on Current Shunts

Tags: current-measurement, shunt

I have an application where a Current shunt is used to measure system current by a battery management IC.

The value of this shunt determines which value of current is considered by the IC as a short circuit current, I'm using a 0R010 shunt, and the IC considers a short circuit when it sees 100mV across it, therefore, my short circuit current is set to 10A.
However, I have a motor in my system, and it generates a peak current of over 25 amps.
The IC tolerates short circuits for no longer than 50mS, but my peaks last around 70mS. Is there a way for me to add some circuitry in Parallel with the shunt so my peaks are "transparent" to the IC?
I'm thinking perhaps a snubber or something like that, but I've never had to snub a shunt before (if that's even possible).

I know that I could just decrease the value of the shunt, but I really don't want to do that, since detecting shorts above 10A in regime is quite necessary to my application.

I also thought about adding more bulk capacitance downstream this shunt, but that also increases turn-on currents a lot (more capacitors to charge) and my board space is quite limited.

Comment: Draw a schematic and indicate the actual components which are used. Without these details we can only guess. In my opinion changing the time constants around the shunt (adding filters etc.) is a bad idea and asking for trouble as this will lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: If you bypass it with a cap, the cap would have to have an exceedingly low series resistance (less than the shunt) and an impractically large capacitance. If it were 1 Farad, that would give a time constant of 10 ms, for example. Maybe you can add large capacitors near the motor? Or put your RC between the shunt and where it is sensed.

Comment: If you add more capacitance downstream, you can deal with the inrush using some type of inrush current limiter. That is a large topic by itself. But you probably need one anyway.